# Leaving a battery charge overnight using a bench power supply can cause damage?

Tags: battery-charging

I recently bought a 6V, 4.5Ah **sealed lead acid** battery. I want to charge it using my variable power supply. If the battery gets full and it is still connected to the power supply, it can get damaged? Battery chargers have a "fully charged" indicator and stop charging when they are full but my power supply is just a power supply

Battery info:

- Constant Voltage Charge (25 celsius)
- Standby use 6.75-6.9V
- Initial Current: 1.35A

Comment: it depends on the battery chemistry. 'Lead' is still not clear enough. Is it wet cell, sealed or what? Wet cell needs to be topped up, sealed needs a limit to the current, which is most usually acheived by limiting the voltage accurately.

Comment: If you don’t have a cutout at a given (low) current, you will (slowly) boil away water. Can you refill it with distilled water? If not, can you set your bench power supply on a timer?

Comment: @Neil_UK i edited the post :)

Comment: @winny i edited the post

Comment: Oh, then it’s timer or set the voltage ever so slightly too low. Too low = standby use.

Comment: Standby use voltage spec is the voltage you can safely connect PERMANENTLY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lead acid batteries are typically charged in a CC (constant current) followed by CV (constant voltage) profile. A typical bench PSU should be able to do this, just make sure you set the the current limit and voltage limit on the PSU to match the parameters specified for your battery. For example if you battery says charge at 0.1C to 6.9V and your battery is 4.5Ah, set the current limit to 450mA = (4.5Ah * 0.1C), and the voltage limit to 6.9V. Your PSU will do the rest for you.

Comment: so the battery wont die if it is left connected when fully charged?

Comment: If you set the PSU's voltage limit to the float voltage of the battery, then your PSU will behave like a float charger at the end of the CC part of the charge cycle. This is what a typical (not fancy) lead acid battery charger would do. Many better ways of charging batteries exist see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23658/a-battery-charger-which-can-extend-lead-acid-battery-life but for a little sealed lead acid battery this is the sort of charger you'd expect in something like a house alarm system. For bigger more expensive batteries you'd do something more complicated.

Comment: It will boil off all the water if left connected for a preset CC/CV.

Comment: @winny i should set a timer to stop charging it then?

Comment: Depends. If you are ok with not reaching 100 % state of charge, just set it to the float voltage specified and be done with it. If you want 100 % SOC, you need some kind of timeout. A real charger would be ideal. If overnight is 8 hours, that might be good enough if you start from not fully charged.

Comment: For a typical 4.5Ah 6V battery like the yuasa NP4-6 http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1500696.pdf?_ga=2.172129123.1775071192.1571563363-699007096.1571563363 they rate it for 5 years life under CV at 13.8V float charging.

Comment: Setting your power supply's voltage limit to 13.8V (with an appropriate current limit) provides CV charging at 13.8V, which is exactly what a float charger would do.

Comment: thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: note 13.8V is for a 6 cell 12V battery for your 6V battery that data sheet recommends a voltage of 2.275V x 3 = 6.825 volts

Comment: 6.9V is perhaps a bit high for indefinite float operation, but should be OK for protecting the odd overnight charge.

Comment: @james yeah i know that you are talking about a 6cell 12v battery